# How to get text in span within another span BS

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'am sorry, just a beginner and i feel hopeless..

I'm trying to get the text from a span within a span, using BS.
I can't find the answer to this on the internet, so i want to try here again.

i want to get the 89% from this HTML:

```
<div class= rating-result"> <span class= "rating-value"> :: before <span> 89% </span></span></div>
```

I try by using this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

scraped_data=[]
details= {}


page=requests.get('https://www.swisssense.nl/bedden')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

products = soup.find_all("a", class_="product-item-link")
prices = soup.find_all("span", class_="price")
images = soup.find_all("img", class_="product-image-photo")
**product_rating = soup.find_all("span", class_="rating-value")**


bed_data = soup.find_all("li", attrs={"class", "item product product-item"})# total number of bedden

for bed in bed_data:
    bed_naam = bed.find("a", class_="product-item-link").getText()
    bed_price = bed.find("span", class_="price").getText() 
    bed_images= bed.find("img", class_="product-image-photo").getText() 
    **bed_rating = bed.find("span", "rating-value").getText()**
    scraped_data.append(
        {"bed_naam": bed_naam.strip(), "bed_price": bed_price.strip(), "bed_rating": bed_rating.strip()}
    )

dataFrame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(scraped_data)
dataFrame.to_csv('swisssense.csv', index=False)
```

So the error i get is that i can't use get text, i think because it is a span within a span. I can't find on the internet how to get the span within a span using BS.

Comment: What error? Put the traceback in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Those values are dynamically populated when javascript runs on the page; which doesn't happen with requests. You can instead grab the value from the style attribute. You need to extend your matching to include those items which don't have a rating and provide a default value.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

scraped_data=[]
details= {}

page=requests.get('https://www.swisssense.nl/bedden')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

products = soup.find_all("a", class_="product-item-link")
prices = soup.find_all("span", class_="price")
images = soup.find_all("img", class_="product-image-photo")
bed_data = soup.find_all("li", attrs={"class", "item product product-item"})# total number of bedden

for bed in bed_data:
    bed_naam = bed.find("a", class_="product-item-link").getText()
    bed_price = bed.find("span", class_="price").getText() 
    bed_images= bed.find("img", class_="product-image-photo").getText() 
    bed_rating = bed.select_one('.rating-value, .rating-result-empty').get('style', '').replace('width:','')
    scraped_data.append(
        {"bed_naam": bed_naam.strip(), "bed_price": bed_price.strip(), "bed_rating": bed_rating.strip()}
    )

dataFrame = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(scraped_data)
```